# Creating array of object in view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using .net mvc3 application with angular js. In my view i'm trying to create the input field with ng-model property. Suppose if i have the following code, how i have to add ng-model attribute?

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ListItem)
{
   <input type="text" value="item.name" name="Model.ListItem[count].name" ng-model="???"/>
}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the idea of meshing with backend template, but this should work:

```
<script>
    angular.module("YourApp", [])
    .controller("YourController", function($scope) {
        $scope.list = [];

        @foreach(var item in Model.ListItem)
        {
            $scope.list.push({
                name: "@item.name"
                // add other properties if you like
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="YourApp">
    <div ng-controller="YourController">
        <input ng-repeat="item in list" type="text" name="{{item.name}}" ng-model="item"/>
    </div>
</div>
```